# Comparing strings inside of foreach

Tags: string, powershell, foreach, compare, string-comparison

I want to compare 2 strings in PowerShell. One is the actual date and the other will be read from a file that contains a lot of rows. The row always will contain the same structure, then we can extract a substring for compare the date.
The file will be a plain text. The types of a date and the substring are the same.

MyProblem:
If I execute this code the program doesn't write anything, the `Write-Host` is not executing, even if the strings are the same. Can someone help me?

```
$list = Import-Csv C:\file.txt

#actual date
$date  = Get-date -Format d
$day   = $fecha.Substring(0,2)
$month = $fecha.Substring(3,2)
$year  = $fecha.Substring(6,4)
$date  = "$year$month$day"

#I do this because if I use $list will return me an pscustomobject object
$file = Get-Content -Path C:\file.txt

#Use a ForEach loop to process all lines in the source file
foreach ($row in $file) {
  $sub = $entrada.Substring(7,7)

  if ($date-like $sub) {Write-Host "They are equals"}
  if ($sub -Match $date) {Write-Host "They are equals"}
  if ($date.Equals($sub)) {Write-Host "They are equals"}
  if ($date-eq $sub) {Write-Host "They are equals"}
  if ($sub -contains $date) {Write-Host "They are equals"}
}
```

Comment: What is the format of the date in the file? I notice that you are importing a txt file and not a csv file... If you go to PowerShell and execute the $List = Import-CSV C:\File.txt and then list it using $List what are the results do they match the format that you have in $date.

Comment: You say for each `$row` in `$file` but then never compare `$row` to anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference date string is 8 characters long, but the string you extract from the lines has only 7 characters, so it's unlikely you'll ever get a match. Particularly since you carefully chose your comparisons to avoid even accidental matches. ;) Also, as @arco444 pointed out in the comments to your question, your loop variable `$row` is never used anywhere inside the loop.

I would suggest to simplify the code to something like this:

```
$date = Get-Date -f 'yyyyMMdd'

Get-Content -Path 'C:\file.txt' | Where-Object { $_.Substring(7,8) -eq $date }
```

That would list only those lines from the input file that contain a matching date.

Another option would be to use the `Contains()` method on each line:

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\file.txt' | Where-Object { $_.Contains($date) }
```

but that would find a matching date anywhere in a line, not just at the given position.

I'd avoid using wildcard (`-like`) or regular expression (`-match`) checks, since you want to compare a fixed value, not a pattern. And you can't use the `-contains` operator, because that one is for checking if an array contains a particular element.

Comment: That was the answer. I saw after writte the post. Thanks for your time. $entrada and $ row its refers the same data item like Walter Mitty sais. Its cause the translation te name of variables to english. Once again, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like "entrada" and "row" were intended to refer to the same data item.
Try it like this:

```
$list = Import-Csv C:\file.txt

#actual date
$date  = Get-date -Format d
$day   = $fecha.Substring(0,2)
$month = $fecha.Substring(3,2)
$year  = $fecha.Substring(6,4)
$date  = "$year$month$day"

#I do this because if I use $list will return me an pscustomobject object
$file = Get-Content -Path C:\file.txt

#Use a ForEach loop to process all lines in the source file
foreach ($entrada in $file) {
  $sub = $entrada.Substring(7,7)

  if ($date-like $sub) {Write-Host "They are equals"}
  if ($sub -Match $date) {Write-Host "They are equals"}
  if ($date.Equals($sub)) {Write-Host "They are equals"}
  if ($date-eq $sub) {Write-Host "They are equals"}
  if ($sub -contains $date) {Write-Host "They are equals"}
}
```